# how to use RecyclerView to make a Circle list

Tags: android, user-interface

Just like the picture shows, let in horizontal, every item in my `RecyclerView` will have a `ImageView` and `TextView`

[image]

i want to make this in horizontal[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZSLI.png)

Comment: What you want to ask? Please be specific and show us what you have tried.

Comment: Review this: [CircularFloatingActionMenu](https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu)

Comment: i want to make a horizontal half circular list with RecyclerView

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this ??

Answer (score 4):

You could use this [CircleList library](https://github.com/dkmeteor/CircleList), that it does almost the same as you want.

The effect is made with this [`MatrixView`](https://github.com/dkmeteor/CircleList/blob/master/src/com/dk/ui/MatrixView.java), you can copy it and do the effect as you want.

Comment: i want to have a horizontal view,the picture i show is vertical ,when i use CircleList Library ,there are some wrong with it

Comment: You don't want the circle view?